# Does Copenhagen Suborbital have any plans for what they will do after they fly a human into space?

Tags: future-missions

Copenhagen Suborbital is building a rocket that will launch a human on a suborbital flight into space. Do they have any plans for what they will do once they managed that?

I have come up with a few ideas:

1. Build more rockets to launch more people into space
2. Work on making a bigger suborbital rocket that can carry maybe up to 3 instead of 1 person on a suborbit
3. Work on an orbital rocket

Comment: Their immediate goal is to start flying their Spica rocket (which is planned to carry their first crewed mission) reliably. Anything grander than that is not really on their radar at the moment. Crewed suborbital flight is their raison d'etre. Everything they are doing is building up to that, and until that's accomplished anything bigger would be strictly blue-sky. https://twitter.com/CopSub/status/1379159916917755904

Comment: Their immediate plan would be to bring the human back to Earth safely...

Comment: @JonCuster No, before even that they have to start flying the rocket reliably so they know it's safe enough to risk putting a human on.

Comment: @called2voyage - strictly speaking, the question title implied they already had flown a human to space...

Comment: @JonCuster That's why I was commenting, not answering. My point was that until they do, they are not planning for anything else.

Comment: @called2voyage - I'll work on making my attempts at humor more recognizable...

Comment: @JonCuster Lol, I'm sorry. Curse of being a mod is I get so used to seeing comments like this expressed in all seriousness, it's easy to miss the humor.

Comment: @JonCuster they did try to fly a crash test dummy, but it failed. [heat 1X] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEAT_1X_Tycho_Brahe#:~:text=HEAT%201X%20Tycho%20Brahe%20was%20the%20first%20rocket,launch%20location%20was%20a%20floating%20platform%20named%20Sputnik.

Comment: @ColonelCornieliusCornwall HEAT 1x was always intended to be a test model and not the model that would actually carry a human to space, so it was less a complete failure and more an important step toward developing the technology needed to build the actual crewed spacecraft.

Comment: @called2voyage good point, it was a good example though.

Comment: I think... I hope...